# Sync database data changes using PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, phpstorm

I have a PHP project with MySQL local and a remote test server and I'm using PhpStorm.

I synchronize files from local to remote when I save them.

But I also have a admin panel that make changes to the database. Right now I drop the remote database and upload a new export from local. Can I synchronize database changes (not only structure like a new table) from local to my remote one?

I have connected my remote database in PhpStorm and can see my remote tables but how can I synchronize changes I make locally?